# Retrieve values from DB in Android in faster way

Tags: android

I am trying retrieve values from DB and showing them in listView. I have created a model accessing it through a loop something like the below:

DB handler has:

```
public ArrayList<Details> getDetails(int value) 
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE__DETAILS_LOCAL + " ORDER BY " + "STRFTIME(" + KEY_FULL_DATE_LOCAL + ")" + " desc LIMIT " + value + ", 8";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        ArrayList<Details> datalist = new ArrayList<Details>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
              Details  valueID = null;
            do 
            {
                valueID = new Details(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),  cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), 
                        cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13), cursor.getString(14));

                datalist.add(valueID);
            } 

            while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }
        return datalist;
    }
```

To access it file in java file:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
            {
                String Id = db.getDetails(count).get(i).getID();
                String Type = db.getDetails(count).get(i).getType();
                String TypeImage = db.getDetails(count).get(i).getTypeImage();
            }
```

I have about 350 records in the DB. When I execute above code it retrieves the record and each column and shows up in the log but the problem is that it is slow.

Is there a better and fast way to retrieve the data?

Or the above is the best method?

Let me know!

Comment: It's... **HORRIBLE**! You are accessing the database for each row and for each colum!! You should get all rows with complete columns in a single query.

Comment: Depending on your project, it might be nice to use a library to help you with that. A suggestion when it comes to speed might be Realm. Find out more on this website: http://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: @DerGolem - How to achieve All rows with complete column in single query? How do I retrieve them?

Comment: Find some tutorial, as shown in the answer given below

Comment: @DerGolem: The tutorial given below and the one that you suggest are totally different.

Comment: I didn't suggest any tutorial in particular.

Comment: @DerGolem : You suggest to get all columns in single query? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Fill a cursor with a query which gets all columns at once. As simple as `SELECT * FROM ...` or `SELECT Column1, Column2, ... FROM ...`

Comment: @DerGolem: SELECT * is what I am doing - Please check my code? The retrieve data from model is where I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You are doing `String Id = db.getDetails(count).get(i).getXYZ();` for each column. This means calling ` db.getDetails()` for each column. Ad you do it for each row (you are in a loop). So you are doing that `rowCount * columnCount` times, instead of **only once**. And this is **really insane**.

Comment: @DerGolem : I got your point. but I am not sure how to retrieve them other the above. The column result is sitting inside arraylist of model. How do I retrieve it? That is the question. Is this retrieving the best way? Or Is there better way to retrieve data? For which I am looking for a solution

Comment: Obviously, it's the **worst** way to do that, Please find a tutorial on retrieving data from SQLite the **right** way.

Comment: @DerGolem: Got it. Made a different approach. And now everything load super fast.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) and [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Here is a tutorial that will help you,
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo

Following are other 2 good tutorials
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

When you load data into the [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) you can use the selection arguments for specifying tag, date, month etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but what if I want to pull data for specific month and year? The table doesn't have month and year format? Instead has date format? Is it possible to write arguments for specific date and time? - Same way need to pull data for specific tag, date, month?